# Standard notation for class of lipschitz continuous functions?

Tags: notation

What is the widely used notation to denote the class of Lipschitz continuous functions?

i.e. suppose $f$ is continuously differentiable, then $f \in C^1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lipschitz functions are a special case of Holder continuous functions. The class of functions that are Holder continuous with coefficient $\alpha$ is a Banach space and is commonly denoted $C^{k,\alpha}$. Lipschitz functions are the special case with $\alpha = 1$, so you will often see them denoted $C^{k,1}$. I do not recall seeing some other specific notation for Lipschitz functions in the literature.

Update: Over more recent months I did run across the notation $\text{Lip}(X)$ for the space of Lipschitz functions on a measure space $X$.

Comment: You forgot to mention that Lipshitz functuons are the special case with $\alpha=1$ AND $ k=0$. Also, do you mean a metric space at the end? Other than those minor issues I agree with both your proposals